# In a SQL Query, How do I do a join only on specific conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL Query:

```
select Subjects.S_ID as ID, 
Subjects.S_ParentID as ParentID, 
Subjects.S_Name as Name,
Subjects.S_Order as [Order],
subjects.Sbj_IsVisible
from Subjects 
left join KPI_SubjectDetails k on Subjects.S_ID = k.S_ID 
where
subjects.Sbj_CourseID = 7594
and subjects.Sbj_Type=2
and subjects.Sbj_IsVisible=1
order by subjects.S_Level,
k.SD_Order
```

Each Subject has a s_ParentID. The most top subjects have a s_ParnetID of 0.
I want to add a SQL Join, which will do the following:
If a parent Subject is set to Sbj_IsVisible = 0 (any subject can be a parent), then the SQL should not output it or any of its children. However, if s_ParentID is set to 0, I don't want to do the Sbj_IsVisible check as this is the top most subject.
Here's what I got:

```
select Subjects.S_ID as ID, 
Subjects.S_ParentID as ParentID, 
Subjects.S_Name as Name,
Subjects.S_Order as [Order],
subjects.Sbj_IsVisible
from Subjects 
join Subjects_tbl st on Subjects.S_ParentID = st.S_ID and subjects.S_ParentID <> 0
left join KPI_SubjectDetails k on Subjects.S_ID = k.S_ID 
where
subjects.Sbj_CourseID = 7594
and subjects.Sbj_Type=2
and subjects.Sbj_IsVisible=1
and st.Sbj_IsVisible = 1
order by subjects.S_Level,
k.SD_Order
```

This partly works. When a parent subject is set to sbj_Isvisible 0, it does not return its children.
However, if the top most subject is set to sbj_IsVisible 1, the top most subject does not output, but its children do.

BTW, This is one a SQL Server 2008.

//edit
adding some example data.
This is the output of the original query:

```
ID  ParentID    Name    Order   Sbj_IsVisible
9017    0   'Boot Camp' 18  1
9033    9017    1   4   1
9049    9017    test 1  8   1
9050    9049    test 2  1   1
```

and this is the output of my query:

```
ID  ParentID    Name    Order   Sbj_IsVisible
9033    9017    1   4   1
9049    9017    test 1  8   1
9050    9049    test 2  1   1
```

here's the create table output:

```
USE [Fox8]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Subjects_tbl]    Script Date: 02/22/2012 16:25:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Subjects_tbl](
    [S_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [S_TopID] [int] NULL,
    [S_ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [S_Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [S_Order] [int] NULL,
    [S_ItemCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [S_Level] [int] NULL,
    [S_IsInherited] [int] NOT NULL,
    [S_SortType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [S_SortOrder] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [OriginalSbj_CourseID] [int] NULL,
    [Sbj_CourseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Sbj_IsVisible] [int] NULL,
    [Sbj_SkinType] [int] NULL,
    [CopyOf_SubjectID] [int] NULL,
    [Sbj_GUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Sbj_type] [int] NULL,
    [s_OriginalSubjectID] [int] NULL,
    [OriginalEvalTree_SbjId] [int] NULL,
    [S_IsDeleted] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [S_DateDeleted] [datetime] NULL,
    [S_IsPrimary] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Subjects] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [S_ID] ASC,
    [S_ItemCount] ASC,
    [Sbj_CourseID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UX_Subjects_S_ID_Sbj_CourseID] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [S_ID] ASC,
    [Sbj_CourseID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'bitwise field 1 for regular subject 2 for weighted Subject 4 for X of Y Subject' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Subjects_tbl', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'Sbj_type'
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Subjects_tbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Subjects_S_ItemCount]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [S_ItemCount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Subjects_tbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Subjects_S_IsInherited]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [S_IsInherited]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Subjects_tbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Subjects_Sbj_CourseID]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [Sbj_CourseID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Subjects_tbl] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Sbj_SkinType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Subjects_tbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Subjects_Sbj_IsEvaluation]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Sbj_type]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Subjects_tbl] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [S_IsDeleted]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Subjects_tbl] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [S_IsPrimary]
GO
```

Comment: If you show sample data and desired results, it will be much easier to help write a query than by showing what you've tried and trying to describe how they didn't work.

Comment: Got it. What's the best way to write some sample data here?

Comment: Show `CREATE TABLE` statements and sample `INSERT` statements, then show desired results in tabular form.

Comment: And now what is the output that you want?

Comment: if Sbj_IsVisible = 1 on the top most(the one with parentid = 0), then the output should be the same as the original query. is Sbj_IsVisible = 0 on the top, or on any parent, its children should not be outputed(if the top sbj_isvisible = 0, there should be no output)

Comment: You can use CASE statements in your JOINs if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing to me but let me suggest using an `OR` clause, as in:

```
SELECT s.S_ID AS ID, s.S_ParentID AS ParentID, s.S_Name AS Name, 
    s.S_Order AS [Order], s.Sbj_IsVisible
FROM Subjects s
LEFT JOIN Subjects_tbl st ON s.S_ParentID = st.S_ID
LEFT JOIN KPI_SubjectDetails k ON s.S_ID = k.S_ID 
WHERE s.Sbj_CourseID = 7594
    AND s.Sbj_Type=2
    AND s.Sbj_IsVisible = 1
    AND (st.Sbj_IsVisible = 0 OR s.S_ParentID = 0)
ORDER BY s.S_Level, k.SD_Order
```

Essentially, select information from the subjects table if either it's corresponding parent is not visible or it does not have a corresponding parent (along with whatever your other conditions mean).

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is really getting me in the needed direction(except I changed st.Sbj_IsVisible = 0 to 1, as I need to output the visible ones), however now I've been hit with another problem: If a have a child of a child, it now outputs, since it's parent subject is set to isvisible 1. I may have to find a different approach. Thanks anyways!